difficulty while trying to install beautifulsoup4 on m1 mac
When I run pip install beautifulsoup4 I get a weird message. I've run into many problems while downloading things on my mac, and I'm unsure what the solution is.
yohan@Ralphs-MacBook-Pro-3 ~ % pip install beautifulsoup4
WARNING: Skipping /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/protobuf-4.25.3-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (4.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.5)
WARNING: Skipping /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/protobuf-4.25.3-py3.11.egg-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'


